# Python 3, BeautifulSoup 4: find_all multiple tags with particular attributes

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I can't find the exact syntax for what I'm looking for in any of the similarly titled questions on SO, so I'm trying my luck with my own.

I want to use `find_all` to find two types of tags simultaneously as so:

```
main = soup.find_all(["div", "a"])
```

...this works fine. However, if I want to subset these results to only include tags with certain attributes, my syntax returns nothing:

```
main = soup.find_all([("div", {"class": "n"}), ("table", {"class": "sX sX5"})])
```

I presume this is because I now have a list of tuples and find_all does not support that, but I am stuck for alternative syntax.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select by CSS selector:

```
main = soup.select('div.n, table.sX.sX5')
```

This will select all `<div class="n">` and `<table class="sX sX5">`

---

EDIT:

Running this script:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://webgrabplus.com//epg-channels'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('div.n, table.sX.sX5'):
    print(tag)
```

Prints:

```
...
<div class="n">Albania</div>
<table class="sX sX5"><tr><td>Alsat<br/></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table>
<div class="n">Albania</div>
<table class="sX sX5"><tr><td>Klan Kosova<br/>ABC News<br/>Cufo TV<br/>Film Dy HD<br/>Film Aksion<br/>Nat Geo HD<br/>Digi Gold<br/>Alsat M<br/>Hayat TV<br/>N-TV<br/>Peace TV<br/>DW TV<br/>Stinet<br/>Top Channel HD<br/>Fox<br/>Discovery Science HD<br/>STV Folk<br/></td><td>Radio Televizioni 21<br/>Rrokum TV<br/>Junior TV<br/>Plus HD<br/>Fox Life<br/>National Geographic<br/>Kohavision<br/>E TV<br/>TV Prizren<br/>Rai 1<br/>CNN int<br/>Radio Televizioni i Kosoves<br/>Tribuna<br/>Nickelodeon HD<br/>Discovery Channel<br/>ID Xtra HD<br/>Wedding Channel<br/></td><td>Radio Televizioni 21 HD<br/>Rrokum HD<br/>Boomerang<br/>Film Komedi<br/>EXP Shkence<br/>MTV Live HD<br/>Ora News<br/>ON TV<br/>TV Festina<br/>Rai 2<br/>BBC World<br/>Animal Planet HD<br/>Top News<br/>Baby TV<br/>24 Kitchen<br/>TV Arta<br/>TVSH<br/></td><td>Klan TV<br/>My Music<br/>21 Junior<br/>Film Thriller<br/>EXP Histori<br/>musicAL<br/>News 24<br/>21 Popullore<br/>RTL<br/>Rai 3<br/>EuroNews<br/>TV Dukagjini<br/>First Channel<br/>Film Autor<br/>Travel Channel<br/>Rai News<br/></td><td>Klan TV HD<br/>Bang Bang<br/>Film Nje HD<br/>Film Drame<br/>EXP Natyra<br/>Fashion TV<br/>Albanian Screen<br/>EuroSport<br/>RTL 2<br/>Al Jazeera<br/>B92 Info<br/>Top Channel<br/>RTK 1 HD<br/>Film Hits<br/>Fine Living<br/>SuperSonic TV<br/></td></tr></table>
<div class="n">Albania</div>
...
```

Comment: hi. i'm afraid this also returned nothing. is that syntax definitely correct?

Comment: @gdogg371 Inspect your `soup` if the tags there really exist. Try `print(soup.prettify())`. Maybe the tags are injected through Javascript and BeautifulSoup doesn't see them.

Comment: it's an absolutely bog standard webpage, designed for scraping and thus very simple: http://webgrabplus.com//epg-channels